# IntelliJ Extract Superclass for Groovy Class

Tags: groovy, intellij-idea

In IntelliJ (community edition), the `Refactor->Extract` submenu has a `Superclass...` item for Java classes, but not for Groovy classes.

Am I missing something (a plugin?) or does IntelliJ just not support this refactoring for Groovy classes?

Answer (score 0):

The answer sucks, but the answer is it does not support this as of version 14.1.

https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/help/extract-dialogs.html